# Erro ao Retornar Dados na View - Laravel 5.5, PHP e adldap2

Tags: php, laravel

Criei uma lista de Ramais através de PHP e Laravel 5.5 e estou com dificuldade em exibir os dados da consulta `$users` na view por que não consigo percorrer corretamente os campos com Foreach

O que tem errado com meu código? Como faço para percorrer os campos telephonenumber, samaccountname, l, com foreach?

Abaixo o código

```
    public function index()
    {
        // realizando a consulta para exibir as informações na pagina principal do site
         
        // Logo
        $logo = $this->logo->first();        
            
        // Seo
        $seo = $this->seo->first();   
   

       // realizando a consulta pela OU  com ldap search                           
       $ou = $this->ldap->search()->ous()->find('AD');


       // Realizando um filtro para trazer somente usuários ativos da ou AD e com telefone preenchido        
       $users = $this->ldap->search()->users()->select('l','city','samaccountname', 'telephonenumber', 'departament')->in($ou)
                                      ->whereEnabled()
                                      ->where('telephonenumber', true)
                                      ->get();
 
       return view('site.home.index', compact('logo', 'seo', 'users'));
    }
```

O Código acima retorna os dados dessa forma. `dd($users)`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do Foreach na view.

```
 <div class="panel-body">
                            <!-- Div responsavel por alinhar as linhas  -->
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <thead> 
                                    <tr>                 
                                            <th class="text-center"><a href="">Usuario:</a></th>  
                                            <th class="text-center"><a href="">Ramal:</a></th>                                              
                                            <th class="text-center"><a href="">Departamento:</a></th> 
                                            <th class=""><a href="">Local:</a></th> 
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>              
                                    
                                                 
                                            
                                            @forelse($users as $key =>$dados_users)   
                                            <tbody>
                                               <tr>                                          
                                    
                                                @foreach($dados_users['samaccountname'] as $key =>$samaccountname) 
                                                    {{-- Repassando o conteudo dos campos --}}                                
                                                    <td class="text-center">$samaccountname</td> 
                                                @endforeach
                                    
                                                @foreach($dados_users['telephonenumber'] as $key =>$telephonenumber) 
                                                    {{-- Repassando o conteudo dos campos --}}                                
                                                    <td class="text-center">$telephonenumber</td> 
                                                @endforeach

                                                @foreach($dados_users['departament'] as $key =>$departament) 
                                                    {{-- Repassando o conteudo dos campos --}}                                
                                                    <td class="text-center">$telephonenumber</td> 
                                                @endforeach
                                                                                                            
                                                    {{-- Se for Vazio... --}} 
                                                    @empty

                                                    <h4 class="text-center"> Nenhum Registro Cadastrado!</h4>
                                              
                                                    @endforelse
                                             
                                        @endif    
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                    
                    </table>   
                                        
                                    <!-- fim sm- 12 -->
                                   {{  }}
                                @endsection
```

Erro ao executar o foreach
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a forma correta de percorrer na View os dados desse array com Foreach?

Answer (score -3):

Amigo pelo codigo que postou aqui, você esta imprimindo as variaveis dentro da view de forma errada.
Você precisa colocar dentro de couchetes, como exemplo vou usar a primeira linha de codigo que você postou aqui

{{ $samaccountname }}